# Why Redis Client Use Multiple Address in ClusterMode?

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

Why Redis client use multiple address in cluster-mode for create connection? is this to switch between addresses when one of them has failed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis uses multiple address to setUp application with all the master and slave node available in redis cluster. Redis never switch address it is just redis-cluster responsibility to promote the slave node to master if any one of them failed. After that subsequent request can be served directly from that redis node.

More details here : https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: `Redis never switch address` this i mean if i give `192.168.10.1:6380` as Master and `192.168.10.2:63801`,as Slave, if  `192.168.10.1:6380` suddenly go away, redis client doesnot switch to other address?